# Can a Djinn host a Parasite?

Tags: android-netrunner

In *Android: Netrunner*, Djinn is a program that reads:

> Djinn can host up to 3 [Memory Units] of non-icebreaker programs.
>   The memory costs of hosted programs do not count against your memory limit.

Parasite is a (non-icebreaker) program that reads:

> Install Parasite only on a rezzed piece of ice.
>   Host ice has -1 strength for each virus counter on Parasite and is trashed if its strength is 0 or less.

I'd like to play and install a Parasite such that it is hosted on an opponent's ICE (for it's main benefit of reducing that ICE's strength) AND hosted on Djinn (to reduce MU costs).

**Is this legal? Can one card be "hosted" on two other cards at once?**

Comment: I don't see what a computer program has to do with board and card games.

Comment: @TomAu ? Android: Netrunner is a card game...

Comment: @TomAu Designed by Richard Garfield. Definitely on-topic. [Boardgamegeek link.](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/124742/android-netrunner)

Comment: @ghoppe: I guess it was my mistake. But that's the conclusion I came to when I saw the word "program." I thought it might be better for the RPG site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, a card can't be hosted on two different cards at the same time. From the Netrunner FAQ on Fantasy Flight's website:

> Can the Runner install Parasite on a piece of ice but host it on 
>   Djinn?
>
> No. A card or counter can only be hosted in one place at a time. 
>   Parasite has the restriction that it must be installed on a piece of 
>   ice, and therefore it cannot also be hosted by Djinn